# SOAP request with mtom attachment: No attachment for id <id> found in [attachment]

Tags: soapui, mtom

I try to connect to a SOAP web service using SoapUI (5.3.0). Additionally an mtom attachment should be send along. But it seems that there is some problem sending the attachment - I always get the following error message as a response:

> No attachment for  id `someID` found in [NameOfTheAttachmentFile.txt]

Here is what I did:

1. Enabled the request property 'Enable MTOM'
2. Added an attachment (in the Attchment section)
3. Added some cid:12345
4. Selected that cid within the "Part" column of the attachment

And here is part of the request:

```
<ws:stream mimeType="text/plain" uuid="0815" filename="Example.txt" ...>
     <ws:documentData>cid:1234</ws:documentData>
</ws:stream>
```

And as I can see in SoapUI's Raw view the document is send alongside the request... Any ideas whats causing the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem.
Even though I "connected" the cid with the attachment SoapUI is not using that cid in the mtmom `Content-ID` section. So originally `cid:1234` was used (and selected in the 'Part' column of the attachments). But when looking at the request SoapUI is using the file name:

```
Content-ID: <Example.txt>
```

Now when changing either

- the `ContentID` manually to 1234 (in the attachement section) or
- using the file name as `cid:Example.txt` then it is working.

It would have been helpful (similar to Part) if the `Content-ID` would be selectable or be prefilled with the existing cid in SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

I shared this one since it might help anyone running into the same error by another cause:

The same behaviour also shows up when the server could not add or create the attachment. In my case the inputstream, which should contain information for the attachment, had an i/o issue and could not be consumed properly.

The problem was solved by not using the inputstream of the source directly (which was a respsonse of another service).

Debugging the soap-part on server side is definetly helpful on this one.